# jQuery validation - Custom regex to check comma separated value

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have bellow html form which has only filed and submit button. Field name is `names` which is holding comma separated value like this `Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob,Srlawr,Jack,`.

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="frmUsers" method="post" action="#">
    <div>
    <label for="names">Names:</label>
    <input type="text" name="names" id="names" value="Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob,Srlawr,">
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

I am using jQuery validation for validating form. Now I have also created custom regex but I don't know how to create regex for my example.

**Now I want to validate form like this condition:**

```
   if comma value is more then 3 like (Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob,Srlawr,) display error
   else don't display error.
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // Names Custom Regex
    $.validator.addMethod("NamesRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,500}$/i.test(value);
    }, "Required field");

    $("#frmUsers").validate({
    rules: {
        names: {
        required: true,
        NamesRegex: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "names": {
        required: "Required field"
        }
    }
    });
});
```

**What is valid result and not valid result:**

```
Valid: Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob, 
Invalid: Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob,Srlawr,
```

**Note: Please don't ignore last comma in regex which is important me.**

Any Idea How to create regex for this way.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob,Srlawr,` valid?

Comment: Yes I want to validate last comma also. I don't want to ignore that too.

Comment: @Mr.Happy could you post some examples for vaild and invalid matches?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Valid: Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob, Invalid: Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob,Srlawr,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+,){1,3}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wB1qU1/10)

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
(?:                      group, but do not capture (between 1 and 3
                         times):
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
  [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                           times)
  ,                        ','
){1,3}                   end of grouping
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Comment: Works great for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the values are comma delimited, you could convert it to an array and test the length:

```
$.validator.addMethod("NamesRegex", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.split(',').length <= 3;
}, "Required field");
```

You could also extend this to remove trailing commas if needed.

Comment: shouldn't there be a comma in `split(",");`?

Comment: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) it says: `Optional. Specifies the character, or the regular expression, to use for splitting the string. If omitted, the entire string will be returned (an array with only one item)`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wcY2z/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with the split function

```
var count = $('#names').val().split(',').length
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the commas in your string you could use

```
 <YourStringVar>.split(",").length - 1
```

to get number of commas and then validate depending on enough commas.

Answer (score 0):

All the current solutions use `split` or `RegExp`, but it's fastest to simply count the commas like so:

```
commas = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if (value[i] === ',') commas++;
    if (commas > 3) return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can do in this way

```
var string="Salvis,Sumeet,Jacob,Srlawrjhkjh"

if(string.match(/,/g).length >3)
    alert("Incorrect")
   else
      alert("correct")
```